# Writing structure variables to file in c++

Tags: c++, file

I am trying to store a structure variable in a file in visual c++. Here is my code-

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

struct node {
    int key;
};

int main() {
    node n1, n2;
    n1.key = 39;
    ofstream fout("data.txt", ios::out);
    //fout.seekp(0);
    fout.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&n1), sizeof(node));
    std::cout << "position of put pointer after write: " << fout.tellp() << '\n';
    //fin.seekg(-1);
    ifstream fin("data.txt", ios::in);
    fin.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&n2), sizeof(node));
    std::cout << "Key: " << n2.key;
    return 0;
}
```

When reading the structure back, the value in the key field is a junk value. Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: Since the file is still held open by `fout`, opening it by `fin` likely fails due to sharing violation. Close `fout` first.

Answer (score 1):

Close fout before you open fin. This works.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

struct node {
    int key;
};

int main() {
    node n1, n2;
    n1.key = 39;
    ofstream fout("data.txt", ios::out);
    //fout.seekp(0);
    fout.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&n1.key), sizeof(node));
    std::cout << "position of put pointer after write: " << fout.tellp() << '\n';
    fout.close();
    //fin.seekg(-1);
    ifstream fin("data.txt", ios::in);
    fin.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&n2.key), sizeof(node));
    std::cout << "Key: " << n2.key;
    return 0;
}
```